# How to run xampp multiple on one computer with different PHP and MySql versions

Tags: xampp

I wanted to run mysql multiple times.
I try but get this error:

[image]

Comment: HI, can you provide a little more information on what you are trying to do?  It is also very helpful to share the code that you are trying to use.

Comment: I just whana to run two different mysql version on one computer i use xampp 1.7.1 and -5.5.30-6-VC11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this guide help you [install and run multiple xampp](http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-install-and-run-multiple-versions-of-xampp-on-your-computer)